# How do I compare an input to strings in a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, char, passwords

I want to create a password program that checks to see if a special character is inside an input.

So I created a list with some special characters so that if just one or multiple symbols are detected in the input, then it should do something:

```
SpecialSymbols =['$', '@', '#', '%']
Password = input("type password")

if Password in SpecialSymbols:
    print("strong password")
else:
    print("no special character detected")
```

I think I need to use a for loop as well in which case it prints all items. Or I may need to check just specific characters and not the entire input, how do I do this?

Comment: `if all(x in SpecialSymbols for x in Password): print("strong password")`? or `if any(x in SpecialSymbols for x in Password): print("strong password")`?

Comment: Did you mean `if SpecialSymbols in Password:`?

Comment: `strong = False` `for symbol in SpecialSymbols:if symbol in Password:strong=True` `if strong:print(strong password)` - Difficult to print several lines in one line, tell me if it isn't clear for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any` (if there should be at least one special char from the list) or `all` if there must be all special chars from the list in the input string.

```py
if any(x in SpecialSymbols for x in Password):
if all(x in SpecialSymbols for x in Password):
```

See [a Python demo](https://ideone.com/i218tn):

```py
SpecialSymbols =['$', '@', '#', '%']
Passwords = ["String #$%@", "String #1", "String"]
for Password in Passwords:
    if any(x in SpecialSymbols for x in Password):
        print("strong password")
    else:
        print("no special character detected")
```

Output for this snippet:

```py
strong password
strong password
no special character detected
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the string

```py
SpecialSymbols =['$', '@', '#', '%']
Password = input("type password")
strong = False
for c in Password:
    if c in SpecialSymbols:
        strong = True
        break
if strong:
    print("Password is strong")
else:
    print('password is weak')
```

Answer (score 2):

This code detects how many of the special characters are in the password.

```py
SpecialSymbols =['$', '@', '#', '%']
Password = input("type password")

number = 0
for symbol in SpecialSymbols: # for each symbol
    if symbol in Password: # check if it is in the password
        number += 1

if number >= 1: # symbol detected in the password
    print("strong password (%d special symbols in)" % number)
else:
    print("no special character detected")
```

More compact: only check if there is any symbol, not using a counter of occurrences but a boolean `strong` value:

```py
strong = False
for symbol in SpecialSymbols:
    if symbol in Password:
        strong = True
        break

if strong:
    print("strong password")
else:
    print("no special character detected")
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, I have created a function that is going to check for each letter in the word if it is a special character. If it is, then it is going to higher the `score` and return true. Then you can use this function for the input password.

Here is the code :

```
SpecialSymbols =['$', '@', '#', '%']
Password = input("type password")

def strongPassword(password):
    score = 0
    for letter in Password:
        for spec in SpecialSymbols:
            if letter == spec :
                score = score + 1
    print(score)
    if score : 
        return True

strongPassword(Password)

if strongPassword(Password):
    print("strong password")
else:
    print("no special character detected")
```